# How can I use computed variables in key:value list in AppleScript

Tags: list, applescript

How to generate an Array (list) like

```
set myList to {key1:"foo1", key2:"foo2"}
```

I would like to increment keys in a repeat-loop.
This is what I have tested so far:

```
-- hardcoded key:value pair works fine
set mySimpleList to {key1:"foo1"} --> result OK: {key1:"foo1"} 

-- generated value works too
set i to 1
set myValue to "foo" & i
set myGoodList to {key1:myValue} --> result OK: {key1:"foo1"} 

-- generated key fails
set i to 1
set k to "key" & i --> "key1"
set myValue to "foo" & i
set myFailedList to {k:myValue} --> failed: {k:"foo1"}
```

Where ist the error? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: That is not an Array. AppleScript doesn't have arrays. It has _lists_. But that is not a list either. It is a _record_, and records are not like dictionaries. From my book: "Please pretend now that I’m jumping up and down, waving a big red flag and screaming: the names of a record’s items are _properties._ The names are not strings; the names are not any kind of variable or value. They are effectively tokens created by AppleScript at compile time, like the names of variables." So, no way to do what you're evidently trying to do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You could use an [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?language=objc) via AppleScriptObjC, but your example doesn't look like a good way to use it (or a record).

Answer (score 1):

*Records* are AppleScript's half-arsed version of what other languages refer to as *dictionaries* or *associative arrays* (although these are slightly different entities, but the minutiae aren't significant for now).  Unlike dictionaries, which have accessible keys and values one can operate on, records have inaccessible keys (called *properties*) and accessible values for a known, named property.

Values in the record are read by way of syntax that takes the form *`<property> of <record>`*.  Because the property is an identifier, and not a string, it can't be substituted out for a proxy, such as a variable, since this is just another identifier that will be treated as a property reference that likely doesn't exist in the record.

Your easiest solution is to use paired lists of the form `{<key>, <value>}`.  Lists are easy-to-use if not especially efficient at what they do.  It does mean you'd have to write your own handlers for, say, finding a specific value given a key, but that's reasonably straight forward.

Of course, since you want keys that increment in value, then that's exactly what a straightforward list is: indexed values ordered by integer keys that start at 1 and increment with each element to its right.

[`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary?language=objc) is an AppleScriptObjC class that allows conversion of records into dictionaries.  They are represented as an opaque reference type to an Objective-C object, so it lacks the visual form of records.  But it allows manipulation of keys and values, but the trade off is the need to convert back and forth between the opaque type and an AppleScript type.

---

Technically, records's properties are compiled into the script, so they aren't something that one would expect to generate on-the-fly during runtime.  If you *really* ***really*** want to, you can actually do this, but its value might be mitigated by the work involved:

```
set entries to {"key1", "foo1", "key2", "foo2", ...}
set _Ref to {«class usrf»:entries}'s contents as anything
--> {key1:"foo1", key2:"foo2", ...}
```

Unwrapping (serialising) a record is irksome, and relies on the clipboard, which isn't ideal:

```
set the clipboard to _Ref
get the clipboard as list
--> {"key1", "foo1", "key2", "foo2", ...}
```

I don't recommend doing any of this, by the way, but it's there if you want to.

Comment: “Records are AppleScript's version of … dictionaries” – Nope. A record is AppleScript’s version of a C-style struct: a set of *properties*. AS doesn’t have a dictionary type so options there are 1. use `NSMutableDictionary` (fast, has limitations), 2. use a [3rd-party object](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib), or roll an associative list or other data structure by hand (a chore). However, since OP is talking about accessing items by index, it does sound like an ordered array (AS list) is the appropriate choice, which avoids the issue entirely.

Comment: @has I was tailoring the level of technicality to what I perceived would be a reasonable match for the OP.  I don't think drawing analogies to a struct would have been especially helpful, as it then entails describing what a struct is.  The analogy drawn between records and dictionaries is one that is a lot more accessible to a great deal more casual users.

Comment: “The analogy drawn between records and dictionaries” Is *wrong*. A dictionary is a collection of arbitrary key-value pairs. A record is a collection of predefined properties; a collection of variables if you will. They are completely unrelated datatypes. OP’s whole problem was they were wrongly trying to do a dictionary’s job using a record, thus understanding the difference and when each is—and isn’t—appropriate is essential to correcting that. OP is capable of learning; that’s why they’re here. We should do them the courtesy of not giving them wrong information.

Comment: @has I think you don't know what an analogy is. My second degree was computer science, so I'm familiar with the definitions.  Whilst I take your point regarding the OP's objective and the technical deconstruction has relevance, I already deliberated with myself on how to approach this, and in the absence of indicators of either a technical background or interest on the OP's part, I chose to use what the two data types have in common on the surface to frame a simplistic concept, not go unpacking the internals which would be neither beneficial nor appropriate. [1/2]

Comment: I indicated their natures weren't in fact the same in my opening, which I believe is entirely sufficient at this stage.   If the OP wishes to enquire further, he's free to do so.  I think the point you're making is valid, and would be very pertinent as part of an answer to a different question.  Had I asked the question, the answer above would not be appropriate. But this is not about simply communicating ***at*** someone to demonstrate how much we know. It's about moderating how and what we offer against what is actually being asked of us, though I sympathise with your frustration. [2/2] ◼︎

Comment: It has nothing to do with internals. Hash keys and identifiers are two different *concepts*. They aren’t interchangeable in AppleScript. OP is looking to learn. There is a data structure which does what OP wants: a hash table/map/dictionary/associative list. Point OP to that, and if they need further help understanding it then that’s what SO is here for, [not compounding OP’s confusion](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925). Thanks. /fin

Comment: @has “Internals” as in “the technical details”. I wasn’t using jargon.  It was just casual word choice.  Though I somehow get the feeling that you’re not someone for whom casual word choice is a thing. You’re hyperintelligent, you clearly value precision and attention to the small details, and it seems to be troublesome for you when others don’t. This isn’t criticism, just observation, because these are quite a specific set of traits that make me wonder whether there’s a manner in which you would prefer others to communicate that would be less contentious or ambiguous for you to read ?